# annotation in highchart doesn't work as expected

Tags: r, date, highcharts, xts

I was using **Highchart** to plot some time series and wanted to add some annotation to the plot to highlight some key points. I knew putting the cursor on the graph can pop up the context, however, some automatic graph generation is needed and hence annotating is the best approach.

And I did that, with the last line in the code below. However, the effect is not what I expected. The text was located at the bottom left corner, not located at the right horizontal position yet the vertical position is right. The time series are created using **xts** library, which means the horizontal axis is simply the **date** data structure, nothing fancy. xValue is specified as the 900th element of all the time points which have a total length of 1018, so the 900th time point must be in the second half of the graph.

Anyone knows how I can put the annotation at the right location? Many thanks.

```
hc <- highchart(type = "stock") %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Some time series") %>% 
  hc_add_series(x, color='green', name="x", showInLegend = TRUE) %>%
  hc_add_series(y, color='red', name="y", showInLegend = TRUE) %>% 
  hc_add_series(z, color='blue', name="z", showInLegend = TRUE) %>% 
  hc_navigator(enabled=FALSE) %>% 
  hc_scrollbar(enabled=FALSE) %>%
  hc_legend(enabled=TRUE, layout="horizontal") %>%
  hc_annotations(list(enabledButtons=FALSE, xValue = index(x)[900], yValue = -5, title =list(text = "Hello world! How can I make this work!")))

hc
```

The data can be roughly generated using the following script:

```
dt <- seq(as.Date("2014/1/30"), as.Date("2018/2/6"), "days")
dt <- dt[!weekdays(dt) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")]
n <- length(dt)
x <- xts(rnorm(n), order.by=dt)
y <- xts(rnorm(n), order.by=dt)
z <- xts(rnorm(n), order.by=dt)
```

[image: Graph is here.]

Comment: Please, provide a minimal reproducible example to help others to help you

Comment: @jbkunst Thanks, a piece of code is added for generating the data.

Comment: I prepared a minimal example of annotations in Highstock (pure JS) and everything seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xr50ftw1/ What is the value of `index(x)[900]` in your code?

Comment: @KamilKulig I'm sure Highchart library works better in JS than in R. Any clue why it doesn't work in R?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much about R. Highcharter is not an official wrapper - some issues that don't occur in Highcharts may appear in it. Maybe the creator of wrapper will help. @jbkunst?

Comment: Sure I want to help. Please feel free to comment to be sure all is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Let's star with the @kamil-kulig example, this will be a little out of R world but I want to give some justification if you don't mind.

If we see annotations options is not a object but a list of object(s), so in highcharter is implemented the `hc_add_annotation` function.

Now, you are using a old version of highcharter. Highcharter devlopment version is using v6 of highchartsJS which made some changes: before the annotations.js was a pluging now is included as a module with some changes in the names of arguments.

### Example I: Simple

The example by Kamil Kulig  is replicated doing:

```
highchart(type = "stock") %>% 
  hc_add_annotation(
    labelOptions = list(
      backgroundColor = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
      verticalAlign = 'top',
      y = 15
    ),
    labels = list(
      list(
        point = list(
          xAxis = 0,
          yAxis = 0,
          x = datetime_to_timestamp(as.Date("2017/01/02")),
          y = 1.5
        ),
        text = "Some annotation"
      )
    )
  ) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(
    minRange = 1
  ) %>% 
  hc_add_series(
    pointStart = start,
    pointInterval = day,
    data = c(3, 4, 1)
  )
```

[image]

### Example II: With your data

Be careful in the way you add the `x` position. Highcharter include a `datetime_to_timestamp` function to convert a date into a epoch/timestap which is required for highcharts.

```
library(xts)

dt <- seq(as.Date("2014/1/30"), as.Date("2018/2/6"), "days")
dt <- dt[!weekdays(dt) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")]
n <- length(dt)
x <- xts(rnorm(n), order.by=dt)
y <- xts(rnorm(n), order.by=dt)
z <- xts(rnorm(n), order.by=dt)


highchart(type = "stock") %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Some time series") %>% 
  hc_add_series(x, color='green', name="x", showInLegend = TRUE) %>%
  hc_add_series(y, color='red', name="y", showInLegend = TRUE) %>% 
  hc_add_series(z, color='blue', name="z", showInLegend = TRUE) %>% 
  hc_navigator(enabled=FALSE) %>% 
  hc_scrollbar(enabled=FALSE) %>%
  hc_legend(enabled=TRUE, layout="horizontal") %>%
  hc_add_annotation(
    labels = list(
      list(
        point = list(
          xAxis = 0,
          yAxis = 0,
          x = datetime_to_timestamp(as.Date(index(x)[900])),
          y = 1
        ),
        text = "Hello world! How can I make this work!"
      )
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for putting this up. I tried your script but got a graph with no annotation. I also looked at the output from `datetime_to_timestamp`, and it's a large scientific number like `1.499818e+12`, not sure if it's the reason why it works or it doesn't, but just wondering if there's any other settings or options or maybe the OS you didn't provide in the code. I'm using RStudio on Windows 10. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the _development_ version of highcharter?

Comment: I'm using the Highchart R library, not any other version of it.

Comment: The _development_ refers to the latest version of the package (which probably is not on CRAN yet), which have the new version of higchartsJS, fixed bugs, new functionalities, etc. Please, see https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter#installation